# Firefox new tab page: how to rehabilitate a previously removed thumbnail?

Tags: firefox

It happened to me to do too much cleaning of thumbnails in the firefox new tab page and now I would like to rehabilitate one or more of them, is it possible?
I looked through the firefox menus but it doesn't seem to me to see an interface to control the removed/pinned thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add site you want to your bookmarks and drag-n-drop to home screen. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites